# Base and dimension in a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help interpreting the answer to a question about the base and dimension of a subspace within linear algebra. I have a subspace W of $R^5$ that is spanned by the vectors:

$${v_1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} ,  {v_2}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} ,  {v_3}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} 
    \text{and} \,{v_4}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix}$$

and I will determine the dimension of W and also specify the base of W.

To do this I put the vectors as columns in a matrix and simplified this using gauss:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 & -4\end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.\\$$

Here I concluded that the dimension max can be equal to three as we have three rows of pivot elements, then I also concluded that you can express v4 = -v2-v3 (I have also tested this and it is true) and the two vectors v2 and v3 must then be linearly independent. But what I have a hard time interpreting is if this means that v2 and v3 are the basis of W (and not v1,v2 and v3 as my first thought was)? And if the dimension in that case becomes two and not three (as the maximum can be)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a hard time interpreting as saying $v_2$ and $v_3$ are a basis because it's *false*. A basis for $W$ is given by the column vectors corresponding to *all* the pivots, in this cas $v_1,v_2,v_3$, as you first thought.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin! How should I instead proceed to prove that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent (and hence the basis of the subspace w)? Via determinants?

Comment: @ida Use what you like: determinants, ranks, definition, inner products :)

Comment: Thanks again @ArturoMagidin!

Comment: That second one wasn’t me; you should thank the person who gave you the good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is exactly three since you have three linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ in the generating system of $W$ and $v_4 = -v_2-v_3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this mean that even though I can express $v_4$ with only $v_2$ and $v_3$, it does not change the dimension or base of w? But it is still true that dim (W) = 3 and $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are its base?

Comment: @ida Base of a subspace is a minimal family of vectors one need to express via linear combinations all elements of the subspace. Since $v_1 \in W$ and it is linearly independent with $v_2, v_3$, it also has to be in the base.

Comment: Ok, thank you again for helping me to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

I would do that  transposing, and performing row operations, to make the whole process:
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&-1&1\cr 0&1&1&-1&2\cr -1&-1&-2&1&2\cr 1&0&1&0&-4
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[v_4\leftarrow v_4-v_1]{v_3\leftarrow v_3+v_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&-1&1\cr 0&1&1&-1&2\cr 0&1&1&0&3\cr 0&-2&-2&1&-5
\end{bmatrix}\\[1.5ex]
\xrightarrow[v_4\leftarrow v_4+v_2+v_3]{}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&-1&1\cr 0&1&1&-1&2\cr 0&1&1&0&3\cr 0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{v_3\leftarrow v_3-v_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&-1&1\cr 0&1&1&-1&2\cr 0&0&0&1&1\cr 0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Therefore, we obtain that the matrix has rank $3$, and the vectors of the first three rows: $v_1, v_2$ and $v'_3=v_1-v_2+v_3$ are a basis of $W$. As
$\operatorname{Span}(v1,v_2,v'_3)=\operatorname{Span}(v1,v_2,v_3)$, there results that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is also a basis of $W$.